# Qt Multimedia API and video decode

Tags: qt4, multimedia

I'm looking to Qt Multimedia API becouse I want to show the same video on 2 different widget. After hacking a little bit the boundled "videographicsitem" example it works using 2 GraphicsView. But this example use QMovie to decode gif, I want to decode avi, mp4, etc.
What can I use to replace QMovie?
Is the multimedia API supported on every platform?

Answer (score 1):

The Qt 4.6 videographicsitem example uses QMovie to decode video, though it only supports animated gifs. More extensive support for video codecs is available in the Qt Phonon multimedia framework, which uses directshow on Windows, gstreamer on Linux, and quicktime on Mac OS X.

It is not obvious to me how to use Phonon as a replacement for QMovie in the videographicsitem, but you can use Phonon alone to build a video player.

QMultimedia seems to be a work in progress. Given what it is doing, it seems likely that it will gain the functionality you are looking for. This could be helped by submitting feature requests or implementing some of the missing pieces.

Comment: In addition to the platforms mentioned, as of Qt 4.6 there is also a Phonon backend for Symbian.